# What does the Android BLE .getValue() output mean?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am working with a BLE Thermometer. I can successfully set the 'Notify' of the descriptor and I regularly get onCharacteristic. The value coming back from the characteristic is a hex of:

0xAA061100020A0023

I can convert this to a string in Android using

```
String value = new String(myByteArray)
```

However, the string is just a bunch of jumbled UTF-16 characters that don't appear to mean anything.

I'm wondering, is it possible that the creators of this BLE Thermometer have somehow encrypted the data so that only their app can read it?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the **[documentation of getValue()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#getValue())**

> Get the stored value for this characteristic.
>
> This function returns the stored value for this characteristic as
>   retrieved by calling readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic).
>   The cached value of the characteristic is updated as a result of a
>   read characteristic operation or if a characteristic update
>   notification has been received.

So, this represents the value of the **BLE Characteristic**, which is **basic data element used to construct a GATT service**.

Comment: Can you tell me how to change that into something that means something?  In this case somewhere in that value is a Temperature measurement.

Comment: You can change the stored value by calling setValue(). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#setValue(byte[])

Comment: I don't want to change the stored value.  I want to read a temperature out of getValue(), but the data makes no sense.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.temperature_measurement.xml

Comment: I've looked at that page before.  Not sure if this can help or not.